# What is the frontier between mutex and critical section?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, ipc, mutex, critical-section

I used to know that critical sections can't be used for processes because they aren't kernel objects. But in Modern operating systems I saw two implementations which could be used with processes.

Implementation with TSL:

```
enter region:
    TSL REGISTER,LOCK | copy lock to register and set lock to 1
    CMP REGISTER,#0 | was lock zero?
    JNE enter region | if it was not zero, lock was set, so loop
    RET | return to caller; critical region entered
leave region:
    MOVE LOCK,#0 | store a 0 in lock
    RET | return to caller
```

Implementation with XCHG:

```
enter region:
    MOVE REGISTER,#1 | put a 1 in the register
    XCHG REGISTER,LOCK | swap the contents of the register and lock variable
    CMP REGISTER,#0 | was lock zero?
    JNE enter region | if it was non zero, lock was set, so loop
    RET | return to caller; critical region entered
leave region:
    MOVE LOCK,#0 | store a 0 in lock
    RET | return to caller
```

So whether critical sections can be used for processes really depends on implementation? And where is the frontier between mutex and critical section, can we call the above code a critical section or it's code for mutex?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Critical sections can be used for user processes *or* kernel mode code.  All that is needed is a means to enforce the critical section's mutual exclusion properties.

The two blocks of code you quote *implement* a critical section by using atomic operations (`tsl`, `xchg`).  So the code is not itself a critical section.  And critical sections enforce mutual exclusion.